# Special method should be called after any AbstractAction-execution

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstract-action

Please excuse the vague question title, but usually I don't do such kind of stuff. So I have the following problem:

I'm designing a popupmenu for a specific app where each menu item is associated with a certain action:

```
public class CanvasMenu extends JPopupMenu {        
    public CanvasMenu(){
       this.add(new AbstractAction("Do some operation") {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                doSomeStuff1();
                cleanup(); // has to be done after every menu operation
           }
    });

        this.add(new AbstractAction("Other operation") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                doSomeOtherStuff();
                cleanup(); // has to be done after every menu operation
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I read somewhere that `AbstractAction` is used for such tasks where you want to add menu items and associate them with some action. In reality, I want not only two such actions, but some dozen of them.

The problem is the `cleanup` thing. `cleanup` should be after *any* of these actions has been chosen. This means, if I continue in the abovely described manner, I will have to write `cleanup()` for each `AbstractAction`.

Is there any (easy/elegant/nice) way or pattern to avoid writing `cleanup()` over and over again? I.e. is it possible to desing something that will only get the action and after executing it automatically call `cleanup`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the patterns:

```
abstract class ActionWithCleanup extend AbstractAction {
       @Override
       public final void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            myAction();
            cleanup(); // has to be done after every menu operation
       }

       public abstract void myAction();
}
```

...

```
this.add(new ActionWithCleanup("Do some operation") {
       @Override
       public void myAction() {
            doSomeStuff1();
       }
});
```

Comment: FYI, this pattern is known as the Template Method Pattern.